# Strategies for sending static rendered images over WebRTC video streams

Tags: javascript, image, video-streaming, webrtc, webgl

I'm using WebGL to composite 2D images into a canvas. I also want to transmit a slightly different version of these images over the network via WebRTC.
What I'm doing right now is using a data channel to send PNGs extracted from the canvas. While this works fine, it's slow (encoding PNGs is not free and also not hardware accellerated) and would not work for animations (changes that only affect small parts of the image at ~30fps).
There's the `captureStream()` interface of canvas that allows me to extract a video feed from its render buffer, which I can feed into WebRTC. Video codecs could handle all of the efficiency issues I now have to solve manually, which would be great. I got this to work, but it has a lot of issues:

- `captureStream` does not allow me to specify an offscreen render buffer, so I have to open up an additional WebGL context for every stream (each requiring multiple MBs of textures loaded).
- The initial bitrate is so low that you only get a few blocks of blurry colors. All my attempts to increase the initial bitrate have failed so far, and the options there are are all specific to Chrome and not supported in Firefox anyways.
- If I send the same image multiple times, the bandwidth issue fixes itself eventually (this is all on a local machine for now). However:
- The initial image is not sent, unless there's some change in the picture from before the connection was established.
- `requestFrame()` doesn't seem to do anything. I read that it needs a change in the picture. Rerendering the whole frame is expensive, I want to avoid that unless something has actually changed.
- Everything does work when I explicitly rerender everything at 15fps, but the browser slows down to a near standstill. It also feels wasteful to send a full video feed of a static image.

WebGL doesn't have an explicit render call (like swapbuffer in some OpenGL implementations), so what is used for determining that something actually changed in the picture? Can I fake that somehow without actually rerendering anything?

Does somebody know whether there a fix for this approach? It seems that the WebRTC standard does everything in its power to block this use case and only enable webcam video feeds.

Comment: couldn't you just re-blit the final output image to trigger the update, maybe just have one pixel change?

Comment: This would not fix the issue of constantly sending a video stream for a static image.

Comment: I believe the default behavior of `canvas.captureStream` is to only emit new frames when there are changes that need it. Over a peerConnection, this would seem to make sense and be efficient. Why is this not what you want? Do you merely desire it to be inefficient so the bitrate will go up? Can you clarify desired behavior? I'm also trying to picture this. Is the end result meant to be viewed as a video, or are these disparate pictures crammed together for some other purpose?

Comment: Think PowerPoint-presentation over the web. With my current implementation, the first slide is so low bitrate that you can't read any text. Also, people expect a perfect image, since my current implementation of sending PNGs does produce that (but other severe downsides).

Comment: Do you find any solution ?

Comment: No, I ended up scrapping the idea and went back to the data channel.